# Dynamic dependent dropdown list using google apps script is not working - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written some code which is supposed to use a value in one column which shows the 'Branch', and based on that it changes the dropdown menu in 'Assigned to OE' (for context an OE is an employee), so an OE name can be selected from a dropdown list, based on which Branch they are in. The list will only show employees from the corresponding branch.

Here is a copy of my spreadsheet, with the irrelevant columns cleared: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dzTYQL1YPX6z6qtV4_tNl4ntBMLqcMQYoPcw6cKuyAw/edit?usp=sharing

Column A of the Sales Order sheet is where I would like the dropdown lists, in each row, and the OE names sheet is where the list of OEs (employees) will be, and the dropdown lists should be populated with these columns depending on the Branch.

The script I have written is:

```
function onEdit() {

var app = SpreadsheetApp;
var ss = app.openById("1UM[MASK]0M");
var OEsheet = ss.getSheetByName("OE names");
var SOsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sales Order");
var activeCell = SOsheet.getActiveCell();

if(activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && activeCell.getRow() > 1 && ss.getSheetName() == SOsheet) {

  activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();

  var OEnames = OEsheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, OEsheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  var OEnamesIndex = OEnames[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;

  if(OEnamesIndex != 0){
 var validationRange = OEsheet.getRange(2, OEnamesIndex, OEsheet.getLastRow());
 var validationRule = app.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();

  activeCell.offset(0, -6).setDataValidation(validationRule);

}

}
}
```

This script does not seem to do anything, but I cannot figure out why.

Thank you

Comment: `makeIndex` is not defined. So the entire code inside the `if(makeindex)` loop won't execute.

Comment: Oh yes, I just changed it to OEnamesIndex but it still does not do anything, so I updated the code on my question. It's weird that it ran without showing that error previously.

Comment: Please copy the Execution transcript into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some things you may want to fix:

(1) This line is pointing to a sheet other than the demo sheet. Perhaps this is the ID of your main sheet. I would suggest masking it for this post

```
var ss = app.openById("1UM[MASK]0M");
```

I would suggest using the following so making copies of the sheet won't break the code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

(2) In the following line you are comparing a "sheet name" to a "sheet object".

```
if(activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && activeCell.getRow() > 1 && ss.getSheetName() == SOsheet) {
```

Instead, try:

```
if(activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && activeCell.getRow() > 1 && ss.getSheetName() == "Sales Order") {
```

(3) Based on the `if` statement, the column of the active cell is 1. But this line tries to offset the column by -6 columns which is impossible.

```
activeCell.offset(0, -6).setDataValidation(validationRule);
```

Perhaps you meant:

```
activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works now when you manually type in new results to the Branch column. However, the onEdit is not triggered by new data coming into the Branch column via a script coming from another spreadsheet. Is there a way to make the dropdown lists automatically appear as soon as new data appears in the corresponding Branch column. Thanks again, you've been a great help!

Comment: If you see the docs, `onEdit()` runs only for manual/user changes, not script changes. One fix may be to set up a time-based trigger that checks the data periodically and updates the dropdowns.

Comment: Yeah I see, do you know of any fix that would trigger the function when any new value is added to that columns?